# Swashbuckle MapType<Type> doesn't work with parameters

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.examples

I've got an API endpoint that takes a ShortGuid class as a parameter, like such:

```
[HttpGet("api/endpoint")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTablesAsync(ShortGuid id){}
```

Generates a swagger definition of:

```
"parameters":[
    {
        "name":"guid",
        "in":"query",
        "required":false,
        "type":"string",
        "format":"uuid"
    },
    {
        "name":"value",
        "in":"query",
        "required":false,
        "type":"string"
    }
],
```

I need to treat that parameter as a string, not a ShortGuid object. I already have a JsonConverter for the type that works fine, but Swashbuckle doesn't understand it so my schema is incorrect (and this my swagger-js client doesnt work). I thought MapType<> would work however that seems to only affect response objects as the schema still treats it as a ShortGuid.

```
c.MapType<ShortGuid>(() => new Schema { Type = "string" });
```

Will I require an ISchemaFilter to do this? And if so, how do I go about writing it (tried multiple attempts but no success)

Comment: Yes an ISchemaFilter or an IDocumentFilter will take care of it... show us what you have done.

Comment: Same problem! any answer?

Answer (score 1):

I will expose my case and solution

In my application I work with Strongly Typed Ids, like this:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(IdConverterFactory))]
public partial record MyId(Guid Guid) : Id(Guid)
{
   public MyId(string guidString) : this(new Guid(guidString)){}
}
```

I use this kind of type type in request classes like this:

```cs
public record MyRequest(MyId Id);

[HttpGet("...")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]MyRequest request){ 
  ...
}
```

In the OpenApi definition is generated a parameter "Id.Guid" (should be simply Id).

If I try to make a request with ?id=some-guid, the binding will not work.

Like @AroglDarthu mentioned, the solution is creating a `TypeConverter`.

The following is the `TypeConverter` that I've created for my case:

```cs
public class IdTypeConverter<TId>: TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if(sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TId), new[] { value });
    }
}
```

I have a lot of strongly typed ids, so my `TypeConverter` is generic (for making specific ones).

Finally, in `Program.cs`, I track all the Id types in the Assembly and register a specific `TypeConverter` for each one, using the `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes` method:

```cs
 typeof(MyId)
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Id))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(t => TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(
                t, 
                new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(IdTypeConverter<>).MakeGenericType(t)))
            );
```

Alternativally, instead of using `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes`, you can annotate the types with the converter:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(IdConverterFactory))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(IdTypeConverter<MyId>))]
public partial record MyId(Guid Guid) : Id(Guid)
{
   public MyId(string guidString) : this(new Guid(guidString)){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work on the query string, you have to add a `TypeConverter` for your `ShortGuid`.

Here is some information on why it does not work otherwise: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4825

Also note that if you use a `Nullable<ShortGuid>`, you will also need to add `c.MapType<ShortGuid?>(...)`. See https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1648 for that.